# Images in question and answers

Tags: discussion, images

I usually post my questions and answers in the form of images to show my work. I use images because MathJax takes a lot of time, and I being a student do not have  time to write my answers using MathJax. My answers and questions are always relevant, but I often get downvotes and comments discouraging the use of images. What can I do for that?

I mean its not fair to discourage someone from asking his doubt just because he does not have time to write using MathJax. Any suggestions on what to do in this case ,I feel really helpless.

Comment: "What can I do for that"? Umm... let's think... maybe don't use images and instead spend some time to write proper questions? If you don't have time, don't waste the time of others, and don't expect any help.

Comment: No one can fix errors, no one can copy it and extend on it, you can't search it. Images are an awful experience for everyone expect you. Don' t be selfish, learn MathJax and have your contribution valued on their content not on how they are presented.

Comment: Being a student is not really any excuse to claim you don't have time. Honestly it may well be you have very little time, but many of us work and have families etc. The people answering are likely "workers" too, at work, at home having been to work, or even other students knowledge sharing with you. Good knowledge sharing is the key, give and receive and do it in a decent manner - ie take some time to write decent questions and you'll get some decent answers :)

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 12):

The purpose of these sites is to create a repository of questions and answers that are useful to others. If we can't find either the questions or the answers because they are not indexed by search engines or even internally then the questions and answers are basically useless.

You are asking someone to put their hard-earned time and experience into answering your question. If you can't be bothered to ask or answer it in a way that will be helpful to *others,* don't ask or answer at all. That way you won't get any downvotes either.

If other experienced users of the sites you're posting on are advising you what not to do, then it's usually a good idea just to stop doing it.